# How can i declare this GridView programatically (Java code)?

Tags: android, gridview

I need to declare this gridView programaticalle, all with java code:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
/>
```

How can i do it? i am searching for code examples and checking the documentation but i can't find the way :S

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you check documentation? Everything is in the [gridview documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android%3acolumnWidth). For example, the code equivalent to `android:numColumns` is `setNumColumns(int)`.
For things like id you'll need to go back to View docs. Width and height will be set with LayoutParams .